# Shibboleth SP: How to pass NameID in an http header?

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth

My web app is secured by reverse proxy where shibboleth sp does its magic. I recieve a saml response where i have custom name id. How do I pass it in a custom header to my web app?

Answer (score 0):

Using ajp

```
ProxyPass /secure ajp://localhost:8009/MyApp/secure
ProxyPassReverse /secure ajp://localhost:8009/MyApp/secure
```

here `8009` is port of ajp so put this only, even if your app would work on 8080.

Another thing, in your `shibboleth2.xml`, in the `ApplicationDefaults` tag add attribute `attributePrefix="AJP_"`, so every attribute would be prefixed with ajp and you can get it with, `request.getHeader("AJP_NameID");`.